# How to get related category/categories in WordPress archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in WordPress. I have few categories of products like these,

**Example:**

```
Product 1 Category (//parent)
-- Category 1
-- Category 2
-- Category 3
-- Category 4
Product 2 Category (//parent)
-- Category 10
-- Category 11
-- Category 12
-- Category 13
```

If I am in a archive page for Category 2(sub) How can I get all other category name under the parent category (Product 1 Category)  as a list.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->cat_ID , 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) { 
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
    $term_name = $term->name;
    echo '<a class="cat-box" href="' . $term_link . '"><span class="cat-name">' . $term_name . '</span></a>';   
}
?>
```